# Qt XQuery into a QStringList

Tags: qt, xquery, qstringlist

I'm trying to use `QtXmlQuery` to extract some data from XML. I'd like to put this into a `QStringList`. I try the following:

```
QByteArray in = "this is where my xml lives";
QBuffer received;
received.setData(in);
received.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QXmlQuery query;
query.bindVariable("data", &received);
query.setQuery(NAMESPACE //contains definition of the t namespace
               "doc($data)//t:service/t:serviceID/text()");

QBuffer outb;
outb.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QXmlSerializer s(query, &outb);
query.evaluateTo(&s);

qDebug() << "buffer" << outb.data(); //This works perfectly!

QStringList * queryResult = new QStringList();
query.evaluateTo(queryResult);

qDebug() << "string list" << *queryResult; //This gives me no output!
```

As you can see, everything works fine when I send the output into a `QBuffer` via a `QXmlSerializer`... but I get nothing when I try to use a `QStringList`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `string()` instead of `text()`, it should work.